# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException при добавлении FLOAT значения с дробной частью

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Все привет, народ помогите плиз целый день мучаюсь.

значит есть такая вот таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[main] (
[Id]            INT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[caller]        INT        NOT NULL,
[ceh]           INT        NULL,
[uch]           INT        NULL,
[brig]          INT        NULL,
[callee]        INT        NOT NULL,
[date_call]     DATETIME   NOT NULL,
[duration_call] INT        NOT NULL,
[rate]          FLOAT (53) NULL,
[limit]         FLOAT (53) NULL,
[sum_m]         FLOAT (53) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

при таком запросе в базу на добавление все работает корректно:

```
float a = 0;
float b = 2;

myCommand = new SqlCommand($"INSERT INTO dbo.main 
(caller,callee,date_call,duration_call, rate, sum_m) VALUES " +
                                                                    
$"({each_off_Row[1]}, 
{each_off_Row[2]},'{each_off_Row[9]}','{each_off_Row[13]}',{a}, 
{b})", conn);

myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

НО стоит передать в крайние два поля значения с дробной часть через {variable}

```
float a = 0.1f;
float b = 2.02f;

myCommand = new SqlCommand($"INSERT INTO 
dbo.main (caller,callee,date_call,duration_call, rate, sum_m) 
VALUES " +
                                                                     
$"({each_off_Row[1]}, 
{each_off_Row[2]},'{each_off_Row[9]}','{each_off_Row[13]}',{a}, 
{b})", conn);

myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

и я получу следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и мне абсолютно не понятно причем здесь ошибка не соответствия количества полей и значений

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: 1) Измените набор тегов (сейчас он совершенно бредовый), оставьте два тега - [sql-server] и тег используемого языка программирования. Можете добавить третий тег - используемый фреймворк. 2) Полагаю, что значения вставляются в текст запроса в русской локализации, с запятыми в качестве разделителя дробной части. Отсюда и проблемы.

Comment: @Akina  спасибо за комент, не подскажите как исправить это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это типичная ошибка, вызванная использованием String.Format для вставки переменных в запрос. Код типа `$"{a}"` скомпилируется в `String.Format("{0}",a.ToString())`. Как правильно догадался Akina, преобразование float в string по умолчанию использует разделитель текущей локализации, поэтому на русской системе, где разделитель - запятая, он выдаст ошибку. Для правильной работы с переменными нужно использовать [механизм параметров](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types):

```
myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO mytable (a,b) VALUES (@a,@b)", conn);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("a",a);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("b",b);
```

Помимо независимости от локализации, такой подход устраняет излишние операции соединения строк и преобразования чисел в строку на клиенте (ибо на сервере для вставки в базу все равно все должно быть разобрано до чисел).

Comment: Ну и sql-инъекцию еще никто не отменял :)

Comment: боже это сработало!!!

спасибо большое , теперь я знаю больше)

Comment: Не используйте AddWithValue! [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)